# php regex - how to get all two digits

Tags: php, regex

I want get all two digits in a text

text :

> text 33 55 66 135 and  132

and I want get 33 ,55 ,66

and here is my pattern but not match any thing !

```
^\d{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/2ClIyd/1

Comment: Use `\b\d{2}\b`

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the string, `$` matches the end of the string. Your `regex` matches only the strings that contain two digits and nothing else.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers it's the beginning/end of a *line* only if you set the multi-line [flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `m`, otherwise it's the beginning/end of the *string*.

Comment: @Mitya - tx, didn't know that :) (comment will self destruct in ...)

Comment: @axiac tnx but how to make it works ?? I use \D\d{2}\D but its not works too ..

Comment: @user4254398 try READING the first comment that was added to your question.

Comment: @Luuk that is not right solution ... because not works if  text = "33 X55 66" , I want all two digits ...

Comment: It didn't work because you didn't provide all requirements in question. If you want to capture 2 digits from `X55` then use: `(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)`

Comment: @anubhava big tnx man it is works now  ...  I must stop coping and paste regex from stackoverflow and read more docs about regex ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to capture 2 digits that should be preceded and followed by any other digits. You may use:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\d)`: Assert that previous character is not a digit
- `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
- `(?!\d)`: Assert that next character is not a digit

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ClIyd/2)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use

```
\b\d{2}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5DYvrD/1).